# Notify you when you've opened too many tabs...?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, loops, selenium-webdriver

I've been trying to make a code using selenium, tkinter to monitor/track your tab and notify you when you have tooo many tabs opened.

I want the program to notify me when I have more than 4 tabs open.
I use the code to open 4 tabs in default and want to see if it notify message me when I opened the 5th tab maually...but it seems to not be working. Any advice? :((((

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from tkinter import messagebox
import time


while True:
  #Use Firefox and go to google
  driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  driver.get("http://www.google.com/")

  #Open tab
  driver.execute_script("window.open('');")

  #Switch focus to new tab
  driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

  driver.get("http://www.stackoverflow.com/")

  #Open tab
  driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
  #Open tab
  driver.execute_script("window.open('');")

  #print(type(driver.window_handles))
  print(len(driver.window_handles))
  print("\n")

  #Counting tabs
  tabs_num= len(driver.window_handles)

  #pop up notify if more than 5 tab
  if tabs_num > 4:
    messagebox.showinfo('yeet', 'fleek')
    break

  time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: @kantypop do you want a windows notification or a message to be displayed by tkinter?

Comment: Can't you already see how many tabs are open? I don't see how this actually solves a problem.

Comment: @JashSmith I want a message displayed by tkinter. I just want to make sure it display and notify me by the time I open the 5th tab.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I just want to make a program myself that notifies me when I have certain amount of tabs since I always end up having too many tabs opened. I opened 4 tabs in this code just so when I open the 5th tab I can easily see if it notifies me or not. I'm aware there're programs that does this job but I just want to try it myself for learning purposes.

Comment: Have you tried `if tabs_num >= 4:`.

Comment: @CoolCloud Yes, but since I want it to notify me only when the tab is MORE than 4, this code doesnt provide what I'm looking for

Comment: What is the current problem you face.

Comment: @CoolCloud It is that when I open the 5th tab while the code is running. It doesnt show/notify me a message saying that it's more than 4 tabs. Yes I kinda troll with putting those messages with ('yeet', 'fleek'). The idea is to get a small notify message that I have more than 4 tabs after I open the 5th tab.

Comment: Maybe because of `time.sleep()`, if you would have changed the position of `while` ,you might get a better result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to display a message box using tkinter you will also get a unreliable main window also that will have no use, Also you cannot only display the messagebox. So I would suggest you to make a message box out of the main window. The code is given below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from tkinter import messagebox
import time
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://www.google.com/")

driver.execute_script("window.open('');")

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.get("http://www.stackoverflow.com/")
driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
driver.execute_script("window.open('');")

while True:
    tabs_num= len(driver.window_handles)
    if tabs_num > 4:
        
        my_button = Button(root,
                   text = "ok",
                   command = root.destroy)
        
        my_label = Label(root,text = "yeet")
        my_label.pack()
        root.lift()
        my_button.pack()
        break
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It works as ineneded. While I was going over the code and learning how you did it. I'm curious and wonder if you could tell me what's the use of root = Tk()?? I print(type(root)) and it shows <class 'tkinter.Tk'>. I research it but can't quite get how this function works. I'm sorry I'm a newbie but if you could tell me what it does in a lay man's term, it helps! thank you!

Comment: Or you could just simply use `root.withdraw()` and that would hide the main window and `messagebox` will be popped up alone.

Comment: @Kentypop `tkinter` is a wrapper around another language tcl/tk. When you say `root = Tk()`, you are creating a tcl interpreter. This whole messagebox that you use is from tcl and there is no need to create your own messagebox when there is already one. You just have to hide the extra window that pops up by adding, `root.withdraw()` after `root=Tk()` and use `messagebox.showinfo()` like before.

Comment: @Kentypop The role of root=Tk()  is exactly explained by Cool Cloud. Please go through that.

Comment: @CoolCloud Or you could just simply use root.withdraw() and that would hide the main window and messagebox will be popped up alone. Tried!! Thank you.  and TAHNK YOU for the explanation of root = Tk()!!!!! I have a lot to learn. and you inspired me. Thank you.